# How to use preg variable in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm using a userid in my bbcode, but I want to display the username!
So I want a query to do something like

```
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE id = "$1"';
```

How is this possible? Or is there any other solution?
I want the output to be "John said" instead of "2 said".

```
<?php
$str = "[quote=2]Foobar[/quote]";

$match = "/\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is";
$replace = "<div class=\"quote\">$1 said:<br />>$2</div>";
$bbcode = preg_replace($match, $replace, $str);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you not using a BBCode parser?

Comment: Like what? I've searched a bit but I can't seem to find anything that seems good.

Comment: like the [native one?](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to modify the replacement/to replace the user id with the correct user name before its inserted into your string.

Answer (score 0):

You do it using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function,

```
$bbcode = preg_replace_callback($match, function($matches){
       // execute query
       $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = '{$matches[1]}'";
       // get user name
       $username = $row['username']; // just for illustration.
       // return formatted string.
       return "<div class=\"quote\">$username said:<br />>$matches[2]</div>";
}, $str);
```

Oh there is a better way. Running SQL query for each of them is not a good idea. So first get all the User ids an contents. Then get all the corresponding name from db.

```
$match = "/\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is";
preg_match_all($match, $str, $matches);

$query = "SELECT id, username from tbl1 where id IN (".implode(",", $matches[1]).")";
// run the query. get all the row in a hash.
$hash[$row['id']] = $hash[$row['username']];

$bbcode = preg_replace_callback($match, create_function(
    '$m',
    'global $hash;return "<div class=\\"quote\\">{$hash[$m[1]]} said:<br />$m[2]</div>";'
    ), $str);
```

Comment: I tried both $var['\\1'] and $var['$1'] it doesn't seem to work.
What's the right syntax?